# PowerBI Add table to existing dataset

Tags: c#, powerbi

Assuming a dataset with some tables has been created through the PowerBI Rest API is there a way of adding a new table to that dataset schema?

I am aware one can [delete the dataset and recreate it](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets-preview/datasets-collection/create-a-dataset), but I want to avoid that.

I have followed this [update table schema](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table/update-an-existing-tables-schema) sample where one can modify the columns of a table, with a PUT to `"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{id}/tables"`.

I have tried PUT and POST to `/datasets/{id}`, `datasets/{id}/tables` and  `datasets/{id}/tables/{NewTable}` uris with correct json for dataset/tables to no avail. Errors are either http `NotFound`, or json error `ItemNotFound` or `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`.

Is this functionality available?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported but it is something that we would like to add.

Comment: Thank you for that. Had a hunch